# Compatibility of functions declared in an object literal without the function keyword (or arrow operator)

Tags: javascript, syntax

obj.B in this example:

```js
var obj = {
    A: function(arg) {
        //...
    }
    B(arg) {
        //...
    }
}
```

In firefox (79), obj.A and obj.B are identical. In IE 11, obj.B is a syntax error.
I want more compatibility info but have failed to find anything about this syntax because most search engines ignore "punctuation". I keep hitting tutorials about functions in general or arrow operators.

This does appear somewhat similar to the arrow operator, with the notable difference that, unlike a named arrow function, this syntax does create a scope, pointing `this` to `obj` when called like `obj.B()`

Could anyone tell me what versions of other browsers this works in, or at least a searchable name for this function abbreviation?

Comment: `B` was new in ES2015 (hence why it doesn't work in IE11) and is termed "shorthand method name"; `A` is just a property that happens to be a function (i.e., a method). See [Object initializer on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It's called a "method definition" (just like in a `class`) and was introduced with ES6. Btw it's not identical to the `function` expression, as `B` doesn't have a `.prototype` and cannot be used as a constructor (indeed similar to an arrow function, but without lexical `this`).